# Separar o print de duas estruturas em Python

Tags: python, print

Eu fiz um pequeno programa em Python que pede ao usuário pra digitar um numero inteiro qualquer, logo após ele mostra a sequência de Fibonacci (número de vezes) e depois mostra o tanto de números pares até esse determinado numero que o usuário digitou.

```
aa = 0
a = 1

fim = int(input('Digite um termo: '))

for n in range (0,fim):
    s = (aa + a)
    print(s, end = ' → ')
    aa = a
    a = s

s = 0
while s <= fim:
     if s % 2 == 0:
         print(s, end=' → ')
     s = s + 1
```

Meu problema é o seguinte, eu queria que o resultado para `input=10` (exemplo) fosse assim

```
>>> %Run q1.py
Digite um termo: 10
1 → 2 → 3 → 5 → 8 → 13 → 21 → 34 → 55 → 89
→ 0 → 2 → 4 → 6 → 8 → 10 →
```

Porém o programa junto tudo ficando:

```
>>> %Run q1.py
Digite um termo: 10
1 → 2 → 3 → 5 → 8 → 13 → 21 → 34 → 55 → 89 → 0 → 2 → 4 → 6 → 8 → 10 →
```

Como faço pra separar esses *prints* em duas linhas? uma para o Fibonacci e outra pra contagem dos pares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
aa = 0
a = 1
fim = int(input('Digite um termo: '))
for n in range (0, fim):
    s = (aa + a)
    print(s, end = ' → ')
    aa = a
    a = s
print()
s = 0
while s <= fim:
     if s % 2 == 0:
         print(s, end=' → ')
     s = s + 1
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/VNtw8i). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/BreakLinepy). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Python/Console/BreakLine.py).

Eu só mandei pular uma linha no local que deseja.

Nomes de variáveis melhores ajudaria o entendimento.

Comment: isso mesmo, jamais irei esquecer disso, obrigado!!